# dynamically creating a XML document

Tags: xml

we have a requirement  of dynamically creating a XML document from the USer entered content from the UI .
Now please tell me what is the best way of creating the XML document dynamically either i used go for using SAX , DOM or manually like

```
StringBuffer.append("<users>");
```

Please share your thoughts .

Comment: "Please share your thoughts" is not a concrete question. Please ask an actual question, within the guidelines of the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't build XML in strings, you'll run into problems with user entered content creating invalid XML.
If your document is small (< 10 Mb), just create DOM Document, and use the create elements / attributes / CDATA sections.  This approach will ensure that the results are valid XML.